# How to control hiding/showing OOTB SharePoint tiles based on a metadata choice column?

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

For one of the Projects I am working on, I am using the Promoted Links list to show tiles on the landing page of a site. Basically I am showing about 4-5 document library links in form of the OOTB Sp Tiles(Promoted Links List) which when clicked, takes to the desired document library.

I added a metadata choice column to the Promoted links list and called it Stage, it has three choices: Beginning, Intermediate and Final.

One of the challenges I have right now is to Hide certain document library tiles based on a change in the stage column. For example let' say if I change the stage from intermediate to beginning or from intermediate to Final, i want to hide certain document library tiles. Not sure if this is doable as this is OOTB SharePoint tiles.

Please see the attached screenshots.As per the screenshot, I want to see library tiles based on certain stage column value. If the stage column is set to  Beginning, then I only want to see DSO Documents and FCMarketing InfoDocs library tiles on the landing page and hide others. Similarly if the stage is set to Final then i only want to see FCCases Docs and Sunflower Corp Docs on the tiles and hide others.

I am working with SharePoint online/Office365. If anyone knows if this is doable, please let me know.Thanks in advance.  [image: Document Library Links]
[image: Tiles]

Answer (score 0):

You can setup unique permissions on that list.  Then on each item, you can specify who you want to share the item with.  When you're in the list (1st screenshot), one of the menu items is "Shared With".  You can use that to specify who should see the links.

Comment: I don't mean it from a permissions perspective, permissions do not come in picture here. Thats not the end goal I am willing to achieve.

Comment: Oops.  I'm sorry.  I must've been multi-tasking.  There isn't a way to do that out of the box.  I think you can do 1 of 2 things.  You may be able to use JSLink and hide the item based on the property or If you can write your own web part, then you can write the logic in to do that and you can store the Stage value that you want to filter on in a property in the editor part.  I'd try jslink first.  That's probably the simplest option but I've never tried it w/ that Promoted Links list before.

Comment: Or Create a view for each stage.  And select the desired view.

Answer (score 0):

For classic view, you could use CSR to hide tiles based on field value.

Sample script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            var overrideCtx = {};
            overrideCtx.Templates = {};
            //OnPostRender call postRenderHandler function.
            overrideCtx.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler;

            // Register the template overrides.
            SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);   

        })();
        function postRenderHandler(ctx) {
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            //var currentItem = ctx.CurrentItem;               
            //the logic how you render your data.
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var metaDataValue=rows[i]["MetaData"].Label;
                alert(metaDataValue);
                // Get the wpq of the web part. This will be used to identify the node with id
                var wpq = ctx.wpq;
                var linksBody = "#promotedlinksbody_" + wpq;
                // "2" is metedata field value, hardcode for test purpose
                if (metaDataValue !="2") {
                    $(linksBody + ' > .ms-tileview-tile-root:nth-child(' + parseInt(i + 1) + ')').css('display', 'none');                    
                    }
            }

        }
    </script>
```

[referenced thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21521.promoted-links-wrap-and-size-tiles-with-client-side-rendering.aspx)

Sample result.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this out and get back to you.

Comment: I replaced the MetaData to Stage (choice column I have). Now when I put metadataValue == "Beginning" which is one of the values of stage column, What should I be changing in the next linksbody field to hide a tile (list item). I want to understand how you are hiding the tiles. I want to hide them based on stage choice value like beginning, intermediate and final.